# How do you concatenate the rows of a matrix into a vector?

Tags: matlab, matrix, concatenation

For an m-by-m (square) array, how do you concatenate all the rows into a column vector with size m^2 ?

Comment: Doesn't matrix concatenation usually mean multiplication?

Comment: I think he just wants to "flatten" the square matrix into a column vector, no ?

Answer (score 64):

There are a couple of different ways you can collapse your matrix into a vector, depending upon how you want the contents of your matrix to fill that vector. Here are two examples, one using the function [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html) (after first [transposing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html) the matrix) and one using the [colon syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/colon.html) `(:)`:

```matlab
>> M = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];    % Sample matrix
>> vector = reshape(M.', [], 1)  % Collect the row contents into a column vector

vector =

     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9

>> vector = M(:)  % Collect the column contents into a column vector

vector =

     1
     4
     7
     2
     5
     8
     3
     6
     9
```

Answer (score 1):

A very important note in changing a matrix to a vector is that , MATLAB produce the output vector form the columns of the matrix, if you use `A(:)`

for example :

```
A = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6]

B = A (:)

B = [1 4 2 5 3 6]
```

You can see the direction of changing in the following image. 
[image: Direction of changing]