# the easiest way to convert matrix to one row vector

Tags: matlab, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you concatenate the rows of a matrix into a vector in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724020/how-do-you-concatenate-the-rows-of-a-matrix-into-a-vector-in-matlab)

Hi,

Does anyone know what is the best way to create one row matrix (vector) from M x N matrix by putting all rows, from 1 to M, of the original matrix into first row of new matrix the following way:

```
A = [row1; row2; ...; rowM]
B = [row1, row2, ..., rowM]
```

Example:

```
A = [1 1 0 0; 0 1 0 1]
B = [1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1]
```

Is there a simple method or perhaps a built-in function that could generate matrix B from A?

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724020/matlab-matrix-concatenating

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this: `B =  A ( : )`, or try the `reshape` function.

http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html

Comment: `B = A(:);` won't work in this case, since it will put all of the columns into one column vector.

Comment: You can simply transpose the matrix an vector (with ' if I remember correctly)

Comment: don't use `'` if you have complex numbers as it flips the signs of the complex component; use `B = permute([2 1],A(:))`

Comment: B = A(:) works and is simpler than reshape, thanks! You can transpose without affecting complex with B.' (a dot before the ').

Comment: Trying A'(:) or A.'(:) gives me 'Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.'  But B = A'; B(:) gives me the right answer.  Why won't transpose and (:) compose here?

Comment: @Chuck Try A(:)' instead.

Comment: @R.Falque A(:)' is not the same a A'(:). (A')(:) fails too.  Perhaps you can only use (:) on simple variable references, not expressions. Definite +1 on Chuck's comment.

Comment: Flipping the signs on complex numbers is called a "conjugate transpose", with the matlab syntax: ```B = A'```

Whereas what you are looking for is the "nonconjugate transpose", which requires an extra dot ```B = A.'``` this won't flip the signs on complex numbers.

https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html

Answer (score 25):

You can use the function [RESHAPE](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/reshape.html):

```
B = reshape(A.',1,[]);
```

Comment: Be careful with the ' operator here, as if your data is complex, this will give you a conjugate transpose. Better is to use .' in this operation.

Comment: @woodchips: Good point. Updated.

Comment: I think **this** is the exact answer to the question!