# Matrix to Vector Conversion in Matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a MxN Matrix and would like to convert into a vector MNx1 with all the elements of the row from the Matrix as the elements of the Vector.

I tried using `reshape` but I was not successful.

Here is the small code snippet and the expected result.

```
  S=[0     1
     1     0
     1     1
     1     1 ]
```

Expected Result:

```
S_prime= [ 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1]
```

P.S: Using a loop and concatenation is not an option, I am sure there is a easy straight forward technique, which I am not aware.

Thanks

Comment: I do not have Matlab here to try it, but you may try `S_prime = S(:,:)`

Comment: It doesn't work, It still outputs a matrix in original form

Comment: Duplicates: [How do you concatenate the rows of a matrix into a vector in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724020/how-do-you-concatenate-the-rows-of-a-matrix-into-a-vector-in-matlab), [the easiest way to convert matrix to one row vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730849/the-easiest-way-to-convert-matrix-to-one-row-vector-closed)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could try transposing S and using (:)

```
S = S'
S_prime = S(:)
```

or for a row vector:

```
S_prime = S(:)'
```

Comment: Is this S(:)' correct for a row vector? I think as a one liner, f'(:)' is the correct answer (at least testing with octave).

Comment: here is the octave documentation page about this feature: [http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Index-Expressions.html#Index-Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Index-Expressions.html#Index-Expressions)

Comment: I had the same experience as Norbert. S'(:)' gave a row vector. S(:)' gave a row vector, but the elements were added to it column-wise, not what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Reshape takes the elements column wise so transpose S before reshaping.

```
>> reshape(S',1,[])

ans =

     0     1     1     0     1     1     1     1
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian, Thanks a lot for your time and help. I wonder, why I didnot try taking the transpose. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

```
reshape(S',1,prod(size(S)))
```

or shortcut

```
reshape(S',1,[])
```

But the question makes me wonder what your original problem is, and if this way really is part of the correct solution to the original problem.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, This is similar to writing S(:) I am looking for row-wise concatenation into a vector.

Comment: OK, that makes me wonder even more about the original problem, but just transpose S and then use the methods. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I think the problem was that just to reshape S as you have given it returns [0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1] which is different as row wise selection rather than column wise selection was requested.

Answer (score 0):

Octave has a very nice function: vec().

The document at [http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~nagy/courses/fall10/515/KroneckerIntro.pdf](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/%7Enagy/courses/fall10/515/KroneckerIntro.pdf) states the following.

```
vector x = vec(X) 
can be obtained with the MATLAB statement: x = reshape(X, q*n, 1)
```