# How to get transition and emission matrix from multiple sequence for HMM in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, hidden-markov-models, training-data

I am doing a sequence classifying task in MATLAB using HMM. I have 13 sequences and their corresponding classes. As far I understood hmmestimate() returns the transition and emission matrix for one sequence and its class. But I need the final transition and emission matrix calculated from all these 13 sequences. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 1):

## What you *should* do...

A sincere, totally snark-free suggestion is to write a couple `for` loops to tally all the transitions and state-emission pairs that are present in the sequences, then normalize the rows in the two resulting matrices (transition and emission) so that they add to 1.  This is what `hmmestimate` is doing in the end, and this is probably how you should do it.

That said, let's go ahead and force the square peg into the round hole anyway...

## and, what you could do

If you concatenated your sequences together, then that could be run through `hmmestimate`.  This would give the correct emissions matrix, but the transitions between adjacent sequences will mess with the transition probabilities.  A trick around this is to augment each sequence with a new unique state and corresponding emission.  By doing so, all the info about concatenations will be relegated to a subset of the output matrix that you can discard.

### Example

Let's generate some data, so the input is clear.

```
% true transitions and emission probabilities
tr = [0.9 0.1; 0.05 0.95];
em = [0.9 0.1; 0.2 0.8];

num_seqs = 100;
seq_len = 100;

seqs = zeros(num_seqs,seq_len);
states = zeros(num_seqs,seq_len);

% generate some sequences
for i = 1:num_seqs
    [seqs(i,:), states(i,:)] = hmmgenerate(seq_len,tr,em);
end
```

### Using `hmmestimate` to estimate

Note that, MATLAB represents its states as consecutive integers, so we need to use the next integer for our token delimiter state.  In the example case, we use '3'.

```
% augment the sequences
seqs_aug = [3*ones(num_seqs,1) seqs];
states_aug = [3*ones(num_seqs,1) states];

% concatenate the rows, and estimate
% credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2731032/570918
[tr_aug,em_aug] = hmmestimate(reshape(seqs_aug.',1,[]),reshape(states_aug.',1,[]));

% subset the good parts
tr_hat = tr_aug(1:2,1:2);
em_hat = em_aug(1:2,1:2);

% renormalize
tr_hat = tr_hat./sum(tr_hat,2);
% NB: em_hat is already normalized
```

Using `rng(1)` before generating the data above, this gives

```
tr_hat % [0.9008 0.0992; 0.0490 0.9510]
em_hat % [0.9090 0.0910; 0.1950 0.8050]
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate slightly on the first solution you've suggested. I don't exactly understand what you mean by 'tally'. Is it something similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16846178/3872160? Thanks :)

Comment: @Rama Yes, just like that answer, but also do it for the emission probabilities.  You could have a look at the `hmmestimate.m` Matlab code - other than input checking and a step for psuedocounts, it really is two `for` loops and a normalization step.