# How to read matrix in following described way in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have matrix:
A=

23   45    65   ------------ Row1
12   29    83   ------------ Row2
54   34    85   ------------ Row3

I want to read row 1 with column 1,2,3 and row 2 with col 1 only. i.e I wanted to read element 23,45,65,12 only. 
How can I?

A(1:2,:)  it reading 23,45,65,12,29,83.

Please help.

Comment: You may want to use [`sub2ind`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) and use linear indexing to access the elements (or use linear indexing directly?).

Answer (score 0):

Can you [reshape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2731032/6610) the matrix to 1 row, and take the 4 first elements?

```
B = reshape(A, [])
stuff-with( B(1:4) )
```

Comment: how can i reshape it?