# Output in Vector form

Tags: matlab

I am getting output of reshape function as follow

```
s1 =

11 
00 
10 
11 
01 
11 
10 
10 
10 
10 
10 
10 
10 
01 
10 
01
```

How to convert s1 as

```
[1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1]
```

so i can pick up bit values
s1(1) will be 1 
s1(3) will be 0 
s1(5) will be 1

I have tried it with reshape and transpose but not picking up correct bit values. Appreciate any help..

---

I am doing following operation with below code

converting cipher text to bytes, then I am calculating index variable (called as p) & formula is MOD(No of Bytes,3).. I have ciphertext length as 5 bytes so Index Variable (p) is 2.. I will always have index varaible values as 0 or 1 or 2 which will be based on no. of Bytes

Say ciphertext is 11001011 01111010 10101010 10011001 01010101

This data is five bytes there for inde variable is 2

11001011 01111010 10101010 10011001 01010101

Now 
for first two bits (11) , index variable to be assigned as 2 
for next two bits (00), index variable to be assigned as 0 
for next two bits (10), index variable to be assigned as 1 
for next two bits (11), index variable to be assigned as 2..so on till end of my bits.

---

Other Example 
Ciphertet with Three Bytes 11001011 01111010 10101010 
Index Variable (p) will be 0

for first two bits (11) , index variable to be assigned as 0 
for next two bits (00), index variable to be assigned as 1 
for next two bits (10), index variable to be assigned as 2 
for next two bits (11), index variable to be assigned as 0.. 
so on till end of my bits..

```
s = '11001011 01111010 10101010 10011001 01010101'
p = rem(numel(regexp(s,' [01]'))+1,3)
k = (0:2)'
s1 = reshape(regexprep(s,' ',''),2,[])'
n = size(s1,1)
N = k(:,ones(fix((n+1)/3)+1,1))
P = N(find(N(:,1) == p)+(0:n-1))'
```

Comment: I'm slowly figuring out what you are trying to do.  While I do so, here's a suggestion: take the spaces out of your string s, they're not going to make your operations.  If you want to display the string with a space every 8 characters, write a function to display the string with a space every 8 characters.

Comment: Ok..Thanks But say I dont have sapces in my string S ..then what kind of modification will need so that for first two bits index variable will be 2, next two bits it will be 1 and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well `s1'` will give you

```
[11 00 10 11 ...]
```

but if you show us the input to your function I might be able to give you the answer you really want.

Comment: s = '11001011 01111010 10101010 10011001 01010101' p = rem(numel(regexp(s,' [01]'))+1,3) k = (0:2)' s1 = reshape(regexprep(s,' ',''),2,[])' n = size(s1,1) N = k(:,ones(fix((n+1)/3)+1,1)) P = N(find(N(:,1) == p)+(0:n-1))'

Comment: Don't put code snippets into comments they're almost unreadable, edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

The key to this question is that the elements are of char type. Then you could use reshape like this:

```
reshape(s1.',1, [])
ans = 11001011...
```

[This is a similar question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724020/how-do-you-concatenate-the-rows-of-a-matrix-into-a-vector-in-matlab)