# Alternative to B = A ( : ) in Matlab

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you concatenate the rows of a matrix into a vector in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724020/how-do-you-concatenate-the-rows-of-a-matrix-into-a-vector-in-matlab)

How can I convert a MxN matrix into a column , i.e. something instead of using

```
B = A ( : )
```

?

Comment: `B = reshape(A, M*N, 1)`. But why don't you want to use `B = A(:)`? It is faster than `reshape`.

Comment: I think because you cannot use `(:)` with function results, only with named variables.

Comment: @Mikhail Very true. A weakness of Matlab relative to Octave...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What have you tried?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724020/how-do-you-concatenate-the-rows-of-a-matrix-into-a-vector-in-matlab)

`B = reshape(A, [], 1);`

Comment: +1 for finding a second, better duplicate :-)

Comment: Instead of posting an answer to a duplicate question, please vote to close the question.

Comment: @Jonas I don't have a privelege to close a question. And I actually added the link after I posted an answer. Is this a bad practice?

Comment: @Mikhail: You can always flag the question instead, if you can't cast close votes yet.

Comment: @Mikhail: See [this question on meta.SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48125/how-should-answers-that-link-to-duplicate-questions-be-handled) for details.