# Different results between Lapack and Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, lapack, intel-mkl

I want to convert a matlab code to C. To do so, I interfaced the C code with the Intel MKL library and included "mkl_lapacke.h".
The Matlab code contains:

`>>A=mldivide(A1,A2)` where A1 and A2 are both square 10x10 real matrices.
This can be interpreted as the solution of the system A1*X=A2

In the C code, I called Dgesv as follows:
`info = LAPACKE_dgesv( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, nrhs, a, lda, ipiv,b, ldb );`
where lda=10, n=10 and nrhs=10

The problem is that the 10x10 solutions returned by Matlab and Lapack are very different! 
Here is the code with A1=a and A2=b

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mkl_lapacke.h"

/* Auxiliary routines prototypes */
extern void print_matrix( char* desc, MKL_INT m, MKL_INT n, double* a, MKL_INT lda );
extern void print_int_vector( char* desc, MKL_INT n, MKL_INT* a );

/* Parameters */
#define N 10
#define NRHS 10
#define LDA N
#define LDB NRHS

/* Main program */
int main() {
        /* Locals */
        MKL_INT n = N, nrhs = NRHS, lda = LDA, ldb = LDB, info;
        /* Local arrays */
        MKL_INT ipiv[N];
       double a[LDA*N] = {
            -0.0091,    0.1024,   -0.2640,   -0.0956,    0.0635,   -0.1776,    0.1257,    0.1048,   -0.0869,    0.0106,
   -0.0865,    0.2401,    0.0455,   -0.0483,   -0.2640,    0.3985,    0.1095,   -0.2429,    0.1452,   -0.0629,
   -0.0428,    0.1669,   -0.0239,   -0.0877,   -0.0893,    0.2085,  -0.2095,   -0.0423,    0.0712,    0.0051,
   -0.0458,    0.0043,    0.3219,    0.1583,   -0.1277,   -0.0598,    0.2033,   -0.1075,   -0.0131,   -0.0277,
   -0.0597,    0.2190,    0.0053,    0.0084,   -0.0741,   -0.0993,    0.3048,   -0.0046,   -0.0718,   -0.0055,
    0.0538,   -0.0734,   -0.2116,   -0.0733,    0.0203,    0.2163,    0.0991,   -0.1309,    0.1299,   -0.0564,
   -0.0415,    0.1569,   -0.0053,   -0.0754,   -0.0855,    0.1912,   -0.2020,   -0.0347,    0.0524,    0.0122,
    0.0648,   -0.1265,   -0.1628,   -0.0357,    0.0592,    0.1129,    0.0953,   -0.0884,    0.0892,   -0.0431,
    0.0446,   -0.2029,    0.1323,    0.0604,    0.0271,    0.1125,   -0.1788,   -0.0454,    0.0663,   -0.0126,
    0.0241,   -0.1181,    0.1255,    0.0281,   -0.0157,    0.1600,   -0.2448,   -0.0524,    0.0855,    0.0092,};
        double b[LDB*N] = {
             -0.2225,   -0.2789,    0.1338,   -0.3709,   -0.4954,   -0.1445,   -0.0116,    0.0254,    0.0118,    0.0098,
    0.0362,   -0.3659,   -0.1204,   -0.0500,    0.1276,   -0.0473,   -0.2388,    0.0701,   -0.3668,   -0.0480,
    0.2351,    0.0922,   -0.0670,   -0.1074,    0.2423,   -0.3811,    0.0791,   -0.2176,   -0.0391,    0.0532,
   -0.0023,   -0.2109,    0.0767,   -0.1575,    0.2569,   -0.1005,    0.2427,    0.3022,    0.0923,   -0.0445,
    0.4103,    0.3612,    0.0651,   -0.0481,    0.1001,    0.5006,   -0.1107,    0.3178,   -0.0713,    0.4568,
    0.1862,   -0.3224,    0.0601,    0.1015,   -0.2129,    0.0320,   -0.1459,   -0.0723,    0.3412,    0.0431,
    0.1613,    0.3168,    0.0876,   -0.0442,   -0.2465,   -0.1598,   -0.1102,    0.2010,    0.0080,   -0.0619,
    0.0929,    0.1286,   -0.2801,    0.0119,   -0.1908,    0.0509,    0.2731,    0.1054,  -0.1830,    0.0112,
   -0.1971,   -0.1049,   -0.0354,    0.5010,    0.0685,   -0.2606,    0.0225,    0.0164,   -0.0140,   -0.0002,
    0.0452,   -0.2061,    0.2058,    0.0156,    0.0198,   -0.0294,    0.0453,   -0.1110,    0.0098,    0.0145,
        };

        /* Executable statements */
        printf( "LAPACKE_dgesv (row-major, high-level) Example Program Results\n" );
        /* Solve the equations A*X = B */
        info = LAPACKE_dgesv( LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, nrhs, a, lda, ipiv,
                        b, ldb );
        /* Check for the exact singularity */
        if( info > 0 ) {
                printf( "The diagonal element of the triangular factor of A,\n" );
                printf( "U(%i,%i) is zero, so that A is singular;\n", info, info );
                printf( "the solution could not be computed.\n" );
                exit( 1 );
        }
        /* Print solution */
        print_matrix( "Solution", n, nrhs, b, ldb );
        /* Print details of LU factorization */
        print_matrix( "Details of LU factorization", n, n, a, lda );
        /* Print pivot indices */
        print_int_vector( "Pivot indices", n, ipiv );
        exit( 0 );
} /* End of LAPACKE_dgesv Example */

/* Auxiliary routine: printing a matrix */
void print_matrix( char* desc, MKL_INT m, MKL_INT n, double* a, MKL_INT lda ) {
        MKL_INT i, j;
        printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
        for( i = 0; i < m; i++ ) {
                for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( " %6.2f", a[i*lda+j] );
                printf( "\n" );
        }
}

/* Auxiliary routine: printing a vector of integers */
void print_int_vector( char* desc, MKL_INT n, MKL_INT* a ) {
        MKL_INT j;
        printf( "\n %s\n", desc );
        for( j = 0; j < n; j++ ) printf( " %6i", a[j] );
        printf( "\n" );
}
```

The solution returned by dgesv is:

```
LAPACKE_dgesv (row-major) 


 1.0e+03 *

    0.3270   -0.5215    0.0049    0.0619   -0.0199   -0.1558    2.9911    1.1247   -5.4283    5.2655
    0.0751   -0.2225    0.1936    0.0490   -0.0678   -0.0201    0.2473    0.1422   -0.4608    0.7307
   -0.0683    0.3846   -0.4393   -0.0885    0.1620    0.0024    0.2210   -0.0303   -0.3558   -0.2766
    0.1779   -0.9302    1.0602    0.2237   -0.3761   -0.0056   -0.4986    0.0816    0.7990    0.7407
   -0.1549    0.3202   -0.0615   -0.0345    0.0257    0.0775   -1.3939   -0.5276    2.5444   -2.5409
   -0.0069   -0.0202    0.0594    0.0175   -0.0235    0.0140   -0.1871   -0.0481    0.3191   -0.2247
   -0.0360    0.1518   -0.1521   -0.0332    0.0600    0.0122   -0.0471   -0.0597    0.0958   -0.3078
    0.0675   -0.1360    0.0075    0.0220    0.0272   -0.0318    0.5894    0.1936   -1.0823    1.0735
   -0.0129    0.0052    0.0142   -0.0096    0.0355    0.0096   -0.2460   -0.1281    0.4625   -0.4091
   -0.0963    0.1961   -0.0244   -0.0417   -0.0032    0.0743   -0.8836   -0.3268    1.5972   -1.6047
```

while the solution returned by Matlab is:

```
 1.0e+03 *

    0.1224   -0.0783   -0.1534   -0.0092    0.0609   -0.0555    1.3240    0.4477   -2.3813    2.0963
    0.0528   -0.1725    0.1739    0.0410   -0.0549   -0.0089    0.0615    0.0637   -0.1206    0.3758
   -0.0706    0.3868   -0.4366   -0.0889    0.1543    0.0029    0.2127   -0.0271   -0.3417   -0.2905
    0.1813   -0.9290    1.0499    0.2236   -0.3556   -0.0058   -0.4944    0.0666    0.7945    0.7407
   -0.0576    0.1085    0.0151   -0.0005   -0.0141    0.0297   -0.6005   -0.2044    1.0941   -1.0311
    0.0037   -0.0425    0.0664    0.0211   -0.0263    0.0088   -0.1006   -0.0141    0.1613   -0.0616
   -0.0286    0.1352   -0.1456   -0.0306    0.0543    0.0082    0.0190   -0.0308   -0.0253   -0.1830
    0.0264   -0.0438   -0.0292    0.0067    0.0455   -0.0119    0.2628    0.0591   -0.4845    0.4438
    0.0037   -0.0281    0.0227   -0.0046    0.0308    0.0012   -0.1030   -0.0717    0.2019   -0.1450
   -0.0352    0.0629    0.0242   -0.0202   -0.0285    0.0443   -0.3862   -0.1238    0.6877   -0.6572
```

Comment: How are the answers different? Can you edit your post to include the input and output matrices? Are you sure you aren't using the transpose of the matrix you want in one of the programs?

Comment: Without seeing your matrices and the output produced by both, it's not really possible to answer your question.

Comment: I just added the code and the results

Comment: Entering `a` and `b` into my installation of MATLAB produces the output that `LAPACKE_dgesv` is giving (that is, I copy/pasted the list in the C-code into MATLAB and `\\`-ed it).

Comment: This is very important, but not relevant for your specific matrices: There are a lot of methods to solve Ax=b problems and Laplak does not use the same amount/type than Matlab always. So there can be cases where you dont get the same results and both are OK.

Comment: Alright..I also had the same result when I entered the vectors as in Lapack..the problem now is that I want lapack to get the same result as matlab and not the opposite.How should I enter the input vectors in Lapack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As TroyHaskin points out, you get the LAPACK result if you proceed as follows:

```
a=[-0.0091,    0.1024,   -0.2640,   -0.0956,    0.0635,   -0.1776,    0.1257,    0.1048,   -0.0869,    0.0106,
   -0.0865,    0.2401,    0.0455,   -0.0483,   -0.2640,    0.3985,    0.1095,   -0.2429,    0.1452,   -0.0629,
   -0.0428,    0.1669,   -0.0239,   -0.0877,   -0.0893,    0.2085,  -0.2095,   -0.0423,    0.0712,    0.0051,
   -0.0458,    0.0043,    0.3219,    0.1583,   -0.1277,   -0.0598,    0.2033,   -0.1075,   -0.0131,   -0.0277,
   -0.0597,    0.2190,    0.0053,    0.0084,   -0.0741,   -0.0993,    0.3048,   -0.0046,   -0.0718,   -0.0055,
    0.0538,   -0.0734,   -0.2116,   -0.0733,    0.0203,    0.2163,    0.0991,   -0.1309,    0.1299,   -0.0564,
   -0.0415,    0.1569,   -0.0053,   -0.0754,   -0.0855,    0.1912,   -0.2020,   -0.0347,    0.0524,    0.0122,
    0.0648,   -0.1265,   -0.1628,   -0.0357,    0.0592,    0.1129,    0.0953,   -0.0884,    0.0892,   -0.0431,
    0.0446,   -0.2029,    0.1323,    0.0604,    0.0271,    0.1125,   -0.1788,   -0.0454,    0.0663,   -0.0126,
    0.0241,   -0.1181,    0.1255,    0.0281,   -0.0157,    0.1600,   -0.2448,   -0.0524,    0.0855,    0.0092];


    b= [-0.2225,   -0.2789,    0.1338,   -0.3709,   -0.4954,   -0.1445,   -0.0116,    0.0254,    0.0118,    0.0098,
    0.0362,   -0.3659,   -0.1204,   -0.0500,    0.1276,   -0.0473,   -0.2388,    0.0701,   -0.3668,   -0.0480,
    0.2351,    0.0922,   -0.0670,   -0.1074,    0.2423,   -0.3811,    0.0791,   -0.2176,   -0.0391,    0.0532,
   -0.0023,   -0.2109,    0.0767,   -0.1575,    0.2569,   -0.1005,    0.2427,    0.3022,    0.0923,   -0.0445,
    0.4103,    0.3612,    0.0651,   -0.0481,    0.1001,    0.5006,   -0.1107,    0.3178,   -0.0713,    0.4568,
    0.1862,   -0.3224,    0.0601,    0.1015,   -0.2129,    0.0320,   -0.1459,   -0.0723,    0.3412,    0.0431,
    0.1613,    0.3168,    0.0876,   -0.0442,   -0.2465,   -0.1598,   -0.1102,    0.2010,    0.0080,   -0.0619,
    0.0929,    0.1286,   -0.2801,    0.0119,   -0.1908,    0.0509,    0.2731,    0.1054,  -0.1830,    0.0112,
   -0.1971,   -0.1049,   -0.0354,    0.5010,    0.0685,   -0.2606,    0.0225,    0.0164,   -0.0140,   -0.0002,
    0.0452,   -0.2061,    0.2058,    0.0156,    0.0198,   -0.0294,    0.0453,   -0.1110,    0.0098,    0.0145];

a\b

ans = 
  327.0114   -521.4858      4.9027     61.9130    -19.8927   -155.8372   2991.1079   1124.6681  -5428.3234   5265.5139
   75.1284   -222.4563    193.6070     48.9504    -67.7640    -20.0595    247.2690    142.2035   -460.8152    730.6545
  -68.2827    384.6219   -439.3150    -88.4497    162.0169      2.3759    221.0372    -30.3170   -355.8296   -276.5529
  177.9446   -930.1793   1060.1675    223.6455   -376.0511     -5.6118   -498.6298     81.5657    799.0423    740.6989
 -154.9540    320.2519    -61.4950    -34.5545     25.7087     77.4924  -1393.8961   -527.6382   2544.4178  -2540.9034
   -6.9249    -20.1575     59.3966     17.5369    -23.5432     14.0414   -187.0725    -48.1027    319.1279   -224.6643
  -35.9941    151.8283   -152.0953    -33.1855     59.9649     12.1877    -47.0808    -59.6673     95.7806   -307.7863
   67.5132   -136.0433      7.5317     21.9729     27.2220    -31.7538    589.3968    193.5591  -1082.2648   1073.4849
  -12.9406      5.2063     14.1874     -9.5474     35.5088      9.6252   -245.9788   -128.1143    462.4924   -409.1096
  -96.2949    196.1438    -24.3756    -41.7405     -3.1993     74.2884   -883.5854   -326.7665   1597.1577  -1604.6541
```

Reshaping an input vector into an array in MATLAB (which assumes column ordering), results in a different input array than the one you fed LAPACK:

```
av = [  -0.0091000   0.1024000  -0.2640000  -0.0956000   0.0635000  -0.1776000   0.1257000   0.1048000  -0.0869000   0.0106000  -0.0865000   0.2401000   0.0455000  -0.0483000  -0.2640000   0.3985000  0.1095000  -0.2429000   0.1452000  -0.0629000  -0.0428000   0.1669000  -0.0239000  -0.0877000  -0.0893000   0.2085000  -0.2095000  -0.0423000   0.0712000   0.0051000  -0.0458000   0.0043000  0.3219000   0.1583000  -0.1277000  -0.0598000   0.2033000  -0.1075000  -0.0131000  -0.0277000  -0.0597000   0.2190000   0.0053000   0.0084000  -0.0741000  -0.0993000   0.3048000  -0.0046000 -0.0718000  -0.0055000   0.0538000  -0.0734000  -0.2116000  -0.0733000   0.0203000   0.2163000   0.0991000  -0.1309000   0.1299000  -0.0564000  -0.0415000   0.1569000  -0.0053000  -0.0754000 -0.0855000   0.1912000  -0.2020000  -0.0347000   0.0524000   0.0122000   0.0648000  -0.1265000  -0.1628000  -0.0357000   0.0592000   0.1129000   0.0953000  -0.0884000   0.0892000  -0.0431000  0.0446000  -0.2029000   0.1323000   0.0604000   0.0271000   0.1125000  -0.1788000  -0.0454000   0.0663000  -0.0126000   0.0241000  -0.1181000   0.1255000   0.0281000  -0.0157000   0.1600000  -0.2448000  -0.0524000   0.0855000   0.0092000]


reshape(av,10,10)

ans =

  -0.0091000  -0.0865000  -0.0428000  -0.0458000  -0.0597000   0.0538000  -0.0415000   0.0648000   0.0446000   0.0241000
   0.1024000   0.2401000   0.1669000   0.0043000   0.2190000  -0.0734000   0.1569000  -0.1265000  -0.2029000  -0.1181000
  -0.2640000   0.0455000  -0.0239000   0.3219000   0.0053000  -0.2116000  -0.0053000  -0.1628000   0.1323000   0.1255000
  -0.0956000  -0.0483000  -0.0877000   0.1583000   0.0084000  -0.0733000  -0.0754000  -0.0357000   0.0604000   0.0281000
   0.0635000  -0.2640000  -0.0893000  -0.1277000  -0.0741000   0.0203000  -0.0855000   0.0592000   0.0271000  -0.0157000
  -0.1776000   0.3985000   0.2085000  -0.0598000  -0.0993000   0.2163000   0.1912000   0.1129000   0.1125000   0.1600000
   0.1257000   0.1095000  -0.2095000   0.2033000   0.3048000   0.0991000  -0.2020000   0.0953000  -0.1788000  -0.2448000
   0.1048000  -0.2429000  -0.0423000  -0.1075000  -0.0046000  -0.1309000  -0.0347000  -0.0884000  -0.0454000  -0.0524000
  -0.0869000   0.1452000   0.0712000  -0.0131000  -0.0718000   0.1299000   0.0524000   0.0892000   0.0663000   0.0855000
   0.0106000  -0.0629000   0.0051000  -0.0277000  -0.0055000  -0.0564000   0.0122000  -0.0431000  -0.0126000   0.0092000
```

---

Edit: to get the same results as in `lapack` you have a number of choices:

1. Change the input vector explicitly, see e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724020/how-do-you-concatenate-the-rows-of-a-matrix-into-a-vector-in-matlab) on how to change the order, basically something like

   ```
   anew = a'(:);
   ```

   where a is the original data in *matrix* form (not in vector form) in `matlab`.
2. Change the flag that tells the Lapack routine whether to assume row or column order. My guess is pass LAPACK_COLUMN_MAJOR rather than LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR to your function, however I can't vouch for this as I have not tested it.

Comment: Alright..I also had the same result when I entered the vectors as in Lapack..the problem now is that I want lapack to get the same result as matlab and not the opposite.How should I enter the input vectors in Lapack?

Comment: @Daphnée I added a comment on this.