# Compare elements of two different size matrix and get corresponding indices

Tags: matlab, matrix, genetic-algorithm

How to compare **A,B** matrices with different size, one-by-one elements have to be compared with each other and get the corresponding indices of either **A** or **B** in **C** matrix.

A={2 4 1};

B={8 7 2 5 4 6};

output : C={1 2}; *or* C={3 6};

here it is semi-equivalent of what I asked:

```
for i=1:s
    for j=s+1:nGen
        if(tOS(p,i)==tOS(p,j))
            f1=f1+1;
            ti(1,f1)=i;
        end
        if(tOS(p+1,i)==tOS(p+1,j))
            f2=f2+1;
            ti(2,f2)=i;
        end
    end
end
```

but I'm looking for shorter and optimized bult-in function in Matlab

Comment: What is `p` here? Runnable code please?

Comment: Post example input and output

Comment: P here is counter which changes rows for each compare to each rows has its specific row, totally it's not a deal hear , thanks  @Divakar

Comment: As Luis said earlier, use some sample values for `A` and `B ` and then tell us what must be `ti`.

Comment: I added a sample of what I mean, _ti_ is just a place holder for founded indces . @Divakar

Comment: [link]http://bit.ly/1wyOauH
@LuisMendo

Comment: How is "C={1 2}; or C={3 6};" derived from those A and B?

Comment: yes, exactly 
same as using either **i** or **j** in semi-equivalent code above@LuisMendo

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to **compare each element of matrix `A` with each element matrix `B`** (your question is not clear).

You can do this very simply with [`bsxfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html). It's easier to compare [linearized](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2724020/2586922) (column-vector) versions of `A` and `B`, and then reshape the result:

```
A = randi(5, 3,2); %// example A, size 3x2
B = randi(5, 2,4); %// example B, size 2x4
C = reshape(bsxfun(@eq, A(:), B(:).'), [size(A) size(B)]);
```

This gives `C` as a 4D-array (of size 3x2x2x4 in the example). The entry `C(m,n,p,q)` is `1` if `A(m,n)` equals `B(p,q)`,  and `0` otherwise.

Comment: Yes I know my question has not asked probably,  apologize.  I already tried this function, but this is not exactly what I'm looking for. I need the real index of corresponded item in. In matrix A or B