# Saving in Matlab a binary file ordered by rows

Tags: c, matlab

Consider in Matlab a matrix

```
A=[1 1; 
   1 0; 
   0 1; 
   0 0]
```

I save it as a binary file `A.dat` using

```
File_id = fopen('A.dat', 'w');
fwrite(File_id, A, 'float32');
fclose(File_id);
```

When I load `A.dat` in `C` and print it, it prints
`[1 1 0 0 | 1 0 1 0]`, i.e. `A(:,1)` and then `A(:,2)`.

When printing in C, I would like to get instead
`[1 1 | 1 0 | 0 1 | 0 0]`, i.e. `A(1,:) A(2,:) A(3,:) A(4,:)`

Could you suggest a way to do this other than taking the transpose of `A` before saving?

Comment: What is wrong with transposing the matrix? That's the standard way to fix row major vs column major issues.

Comment: A similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2724020/how-do-you-concatenate-the-rows-of-a-matrix-into-a-vector-in-matlab